# Can you programmatically change the button image for a ESRI.ArcGIS.Desktop.AddIns.Button?

Tags: arcobjects, arcgis-10.0, ux

I'm new to the AddIn customization model in ArcGIS 10 and I'm trying to figure out how to change a button image for a button. I'm looking for the equivalent to the BaseCommand UpdateBitmap method and haven't had any luck.  Is this a limitation of the AddIn model?  Or did I miss something obvious?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, I've worked something out using ICommandItem.FaceID.  I wasn't initially thinking of using ICommandItem, but it gets the job done.

```
ICommandItem commandItem = ArcMap.Application.Document.CommandBars.Find(...;
commandItem.FaceID = ESRI.ArcGIS.ADF.COMSupport.OLE.GetIPictureDispFromBitmap(bitmap);
```

Answer (score 3):

I have not worked with add-ins in ArcGIS 10, but looking at the [documentation](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/conceptualhelp/index.html#/Building_add_ins_for_ArcGIS_Desktop/0001000000w2000000/) (see heading **Add-in file anatomy**), it appears that you would need to specify the image declaratively in the add-in's XML configuration (metadata):

```
<ESRI.Configuration
 xmlns="http://schemas.esri.com/Desktop/AddIns"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

    <!-- Omitted -->

    <AddIn language="CLR" library="Acme.dll" namespace="Acme">
        <ArcMap>
            <Commands>
                <Button
                     id="Acme_ToggleDockWinBtn"
                     class="ToggleDockWinBtn"
                     caption="OpenDockWin"
                     category="Acme Tools" 
                     image="Images\ToggleDockWinBtn.png" <!-- Define image URI --> 
                     tip="Toggle dockable window."
                     message="Open dockable window.">
                       <Help heading="Toggle">Turns the ACME dockable window on and off.</Help>
                </Button>
            </Commands>
        </ArcMap>
     </AddIn>

</ESRI.Configuration>
```

See also the [Advanced add-in concepts](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/conceptualhelp/index.html#/Advanced_add_in_concepts/0001000004n7000000/) topic, which suggests that graphics should no longer be embedded as resources in the assembly.

Answer (score 0):

The image used in the xml configuration file must have its property "build action" set to AddInContent - at least is vs2012 for arcgis 10.2.

Comment: How exactly does that address the question?

Comment: While true, this doesn't answer the question. Maybe it could be a comment on Adam's question since his answer also pertains to the xml declarative.