# How to launch a tool when my button has been pressed

Tags: arcobjects, arcgis-10.0

I use ArcGIS 10.0 and ArcGIS .net SDK. I created AddIn project which contains Tool:

```
<Tool id="AddSearchLocationPoint"
  class="AddSearchLocationPoint"
  category="Add-In Controls"
  image="Images\insert.png" />
```

and DockableWindow:

```
<DockableWindow id="SearchDockableWindow"
                class="SearchDockableWindow"
                image="Images\SearchDockableWindow.png">
  <InitialPlacement height="360" width="570" state="pinned" position="right" />
</DockableWindow>
```

The dockableWindow contains WinForm’s HostElement which displays my WPF UserControl. Now I want to add a button to the WPF UserControl which will launch my tool. Do you know a way to raise the event which launches the tool?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does the tool "Launch" or do you mean set it as the current tool?  Maybe I'm not understanding your question.

I think you need to get an ICommandItem for your tool or button, similar to my answer here: [Can you programmatically change the button image for a ESRI.ArcGIS.Desktop.AddIns.Button?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/1297/can-you-programmatically-change-the-button-image-for-a-esri-arcgis-desktop-addins/1312#1312)

```
ICommandItem commandItem = ArcMap.Application.Document.CommandBars.Find(uid, true, true);
ArcMap.Application.CurrentTool = commandItem;
```

or if it isn't a tool, you could execute:

```
ICommandItem commandItem = ArcMap.Application.Document.CommandBars.Find(uid, true, true);
commandItem.Execute();
```