# How to programmatically access an Add-ins image?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, add-in

From this thread:

[Can you programmatically change the button image for a ESRI.ArcGIS.Desktop.AddIns.Button?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/1297/can-you-programmatically-change-the-button-image-for-a-esri-arcgis-desktop-addins)

I've learned to change a command image programmatically, but... how can I programmatically get an image from the "Images" folder of the Addins, avoiding to write the physical file path?

Is there a way to quickly get access to the Addins resources?

Answer (score 1):

I guess it depends on what you mean by "quickly".  The images are unpacked into the AssemblyCache under the user's profile.

Win7 example:
`AppData\Local\ESRI\Desktop10.0\AssemblyCache\{3E0AB950-82E4-BF00-EA51-9FC591749394}\Images`

I get the directory with something like this:

```
string dirpath =    Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location),"Images")
```

And then you can use normal .NET file IO to access the files.  And these would be the  files in visual studio that have a build action of AddInContent.

You can also add files with a build action as  `Embedded Resource` and get it with `GetManifestResourceStream`:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/278838/visual-studio-how-to-store-an-image-resource-as-an-embedded-resource/483891#483891

There might be other methods, but the two above are what I've used (I guess 3 of you count resources).

Comment: I'm sorry for my english: "quickly" it means for me a direct method from addins objects or something...but till now I have not found it. However, thank you for your suggestion, I tried it, but there is no Images folder in that path! I'm working on Windows Server 2003 and I get:`C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\Impostazioni locali\Dati applicazioni\ESRI\Desktop10.0\AssemblyCache\{26978580-636C-C40B-39CA-32C16B98529C}` I can see only the .dll files in this folder. Otherwise I don't like the Embedded Resource solution, I hope it's not the only way.